# How to set multiple upload image / files by use of default Contao form?

Tags: contao, multi-upload

I want to upload multiple images.
I'm using Contao default form. Single upload is working but for multiple upload I don't know from where I have to configure it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about backend or frontend?

Comment: Sorry for late replay.. I'm talking about Frontend

Comment: The volumes file uploader is able to do both.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this module by MenAtWork:
https://contao.org/en/extension-list/view/valumsFileUploader.30010008.en.html

Answer (score 0):

The valumsFileUploader Extension could only be used in outdated Contao version.

Try this: [derhaeuptling/contao-multi-file-upload-with-dropzone](https://libraries.io/packagist/derhaeuptling%2Fcontao-multi-file-upload-with-dropzone) (install via composer in Contao 3.5+)